# Displaying charachters in a text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How do i display something like this in my text widget in flutter?[image]

Comment: Text widgets takes a string. So passing characters to it won't be a problem. `Text("Mon,19 Apr . 6:00 PM")`

Comment: As per your solution this gives me a period, i want to have a filled circle with some elevation as shown in the picture.

Comment: It also supports ASCII characters. Can you give it a try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *RichText* , providing the dot as an Circle Avatar and other 2 widgets the text you want .

```
                RichText(
            text:TextSpan(
              children:[
                TextSpan(
                  text:"Mon, 19 April ",
                  style:TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:5.0,),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius:3,
                      backgroundColor:Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text:" 06:00 PM",
                  style:TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, it did work as expected. However how can i give space between the two TextSpan, i can't make use of the SizedBox widget here..

Comment: You can use *WidgetSpan* as I have used and give Sized Box as its child .